# Android: How to execute a method before the layout is initiated/created in an activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I need to execute a method before initiating the layout in an activity. If I call the method I need to execute inside onCreate(), would it be executed before the layout is set?

The reason is because I need the method to return a piece of information that is displayed in the layout before initiating it. Would love some feedback on this.

Comment: Read up on the activity lifecycle.

Comment: `onCreate()` is probably the place, but it depends on your specific circumstances. I think your question needs more information.

Comment: `would it be executed before the layout is set?` Yes, call your method before calling `setContentView()`.

Comment: @PPartisan So I need to access the user's phone to get some data which will be displayed on the home screen.

Comment: @user3519023 Can't you just create your layout first, grab the necessary data and then update your view once it's ready? That's how it's normally done, otherwise (if it's a long running operation), your user could end up staring at a blank screen wondering whether or not your app has crashed.

Comment: @user3519023, in that case you would display some OTHER screen (it may only be there for a moment), start the process of getting the data, and once you've got the data, go to your "new, data" screen...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do whatever you like before setContentView like so:

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        int i = 0;
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

As long as you ***do not interact with views that have not been inflated yet***

For example this is an error:

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // ERROR, CAN'T TOUCH UI ELEMENTS
        ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 2):

Default activity created with Android Studio contains following code

```
@Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //Here is code, that executed before layout inflated
    setContentView(R.layout.example_activity); //This line inflates layout
}
```

BTW, you can even remove `setContentView` and inflate layout programmaticaly.

Answer (score 2):

Do it in `onCreate()`, preferably before calling `setContentView()`.

However, if the data you want to receive comes from the network, then it will be obtained on a separate `Thread` (as no network calls can be done on the main `Thread`). In this situation the layout will almost certainly display before the data is obtained.

A solution would be to obtain the piece of data before you start the `Activity`, pass it in the `Intent` as extra and then retrieve in `onCreate()` using `getIntent().getStringExtra()`

Answer (score 2):

You are probably inflating your layout in `Activity.onCreate()` with `setContentView()`, so you need to put your function call in that method before the call to `setContentView()`.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    yourFunctionCallHere();

    setContentView(R.layout.act_main);
}
```